# How do I swap the current user in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I got a login with multiple users. How do I swap the current user? For example if I run `select current_user` it returns `user1`. I would like to become `user2` how do I do that?

p.s can I add an password to a specific user or only to the login.

Comment: mssql. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Some kind of set connection, depending on API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [EXECUTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) as

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'user2';
```

When you are done,you can revert back to your login as

```
Revert;
```

Comment: Yes but if i use execute as user . Dosen't that mean that i'm only impersonating a user but currently i am not that user . Is there any way to swap the user.

Comment: @Road2PreSchool: yes that means ,you are impersonating that user.there is no way to swap entirely(execution context),you could do all things with just impersonating as well

Comment: Ok I'll accept this as an answer but could u at least just guide me. I've already build a desktop application in java and got 25 people hwo are going to use it so.I created a new login for them with 25 user's so should i use this method with 'execute as user' in the app or is there any better way ?

Comment: You don't need execute as user,assign all the login's users a specific role(if all need to have same permissions),so when they use app,it authenticates them or else you can create an app login

Comment: Last questin sorry. Yes but that's the porblem i don't understand how do they authenticate as a specific user ? How do i tell sql which user is logining in when the only information i'm giving to it is the login name and the password @TheGameiswar